# Is my Azure VM IP address permanently associated to my account?

Tags: ip-address, azure

I've created a new Azure VM using the standard settings in the networking tab.

Now deployed, in the IP configuration blade I cannot determine whether that IP is permanently associcated to my Azure account (and therefore my VM).  The IP is labelled as "static" under the "configuration" blade.

Am I correct in thinking that the only way to "lose" this IP address from my control would be to press the "Dissociate" button?

Comment: Have you contacted Azure support with this question?

Comment: Yes but no help as yet.  MS support says use StackOverflow but it's off topic for that site

Comment: ...Also it appears I need to pay to get an answer.

Comment: Where do you have to pay to get an answer? Answers at SU are free.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which resource model you chose.  With the classic model, it's possible to reserve IPs and keep them in the subscription.  Though the (classic) reserved IPs are restricted to services that expose VIPs.

If you didn't choose a model then you're probably using the newer resource manager model.  For that, it depends on the sku you chose.  The default sku is basic and the default allocation method is dynamic.  That just means the IP address changes every time you stop or delete the resource.  Unstable, er dynamic.

If you chose a standard sku, or explicitly allocate a static with the basic sku, then they are semi-permanent.  It will stay the same as long as the network interface resource stays in the same resource group (& doesn't get deleted).  I've deleted every other resource except a network interface, i.e. the disks, VM, etc. and then recreated them & reattached the same old network interface.  The new VM will have the same old IP.  I've had the same Azure IPs for years.  Once you delete the network interface, though, it's gone for good.

This kind of [explains it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-addresses#allocation-method)

Comment: Thanks.  I found some more clarity on the MS forums and added below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer from the MS forums:

> Once you created public IP address in azure it will be in your
> account, even if you dissociate public IP still it will remain in
> azure account. Once you Dissociate a public IP address from an Azure
> VM, still it will exist in your azure account. you should manually
> delete public IP address.

So it is linked to my account until I "delete" it, not just dissociate it.